# Computing $\lim_{\substack{t\to1\\t<1}}{(1-t)\sum_{n=0}^\infty{\frac{t^n}{1+t^n}}}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, asymptotics

I want to find the following limit:
$$ \lim_{\substack{t\to1\\t<1}}{(1-t)\sum_{n=0}^\infty{\frac{t^n}{1+t^n}}}.$$
I suspect it has to do with integrals and Riemann sums, but I don't see the exact way to proceed.

Thanks for help!

Comment: What's $t$ tending to?

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo.

Comment: Well, I didn't see $ a^- $ notation before.

Comment: Maybe now it's more clear?

Comment: Yes, it's good. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-sided_limit

Comment: Here's a formal derivation of the limit:
$$\begin{aligned}(1-t)\sum_{n=0}^\infty{\frac{t^n}{1+t^n}} 
&= (1-t)\sum_{n=0}^\infty t^n\sum_{m=0}^\infty (-1)^mt^{mn}
=(1-t)\sum_{m=0}^\infty(-1)^m\sum_{n=0}^\infty t^{(m+1)n}\\
&= (1-t)\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m}{1-t^{m+1}}\\
&\to \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m}{m+1}\\
&= \ln 2
\end{aligned}$$
Justifying the last limit on $t$ is not easy.

Comment: @GabrielRomon Isn't series

$$ \sum_{m=0}^\infty{\frac{(1-t)(-1)^m}{1-t^{m+1}}}=\sum_{m=0}^\infty{\frac{(-1)^m}{1+t+t^2+\dots+t^m}} $$

diverges when $ t<1 $?

Comment: Indeed, I didn't bother checking convergence of anything (and indeed $\sum_{n,m} t^{n(m+1)}$ is not summable), but this yields the correct limit nonetheless !

Comment: Double post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3140525/how-can-i-know-a-value-of-this-limit/3140968#3140968